# Is it possible to create Dynamic Objects?

Tags: c++

So me and my friend were thinking about a C++ program when my friend asked me, *"Wouldn't it be nice if c++ allowed us to create Dynamic Objects??"*

Then I asked what does he mean and he told me this story...

*Suppose in my C++ program I had a **class** definition in which contains some data members. Consider having the following **class***

```
class Student
{
   char Skill[15];
   int Age;
};
```

*Now is it possible to create an object whose name will be the one which the user inputs?*

For example

Suppose in my main program I have a code-line like `cout << "Enter Name: ";`. Now please note that anything that the user inputs will be stored in a variable which I created inside the ***main()*** function. So suppose the user inputs his name as *"XYZ"*(obviously without the quotes). End of the story...

Now he asked me that *"Is it possible to create an object of the* `class Student` *with the name which the user entered?! (probably in* `main()`*)"*  *i.e.* `Student <the name which the user entered>;`.

So I thought about this and haven't got any answer yet and therefore I am posting this question in a hope that I will get the answer... So is it Possible?!

Comment: Why not just add a `std::string Name` variable to the `Student` class.

Comment: So you want your users to name your variables? Hmm...

Comment: No, you can't. And there would be no point for that at all. Varialbe names are there to make code readable. They don't have a role at runtime.

Comment: In an interpreted language like javascript (`window[var_name]`) or PHP (`$$var_name`) this is possible, because global variables are essentially just entries in a special associative array, but even there it remains a singularly *bad* idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. That is not possible. You need to have some static name to refer to the new object you're creating on the stack.  I.e., even if you could create it, how would you possibly reference it later in the program since when you're writing the program you do not know what it will be called?

Answer (score 1):

This is what associative containers are for.

```
struct Student {
    unsigned age;
};

std::map<std::string, Student> students;

void enter_student()
{
    Student st;
    std::string name;
    std::cout << "Enter name and age: ";
    std::cin >> name >> st.age;
    students[name] = st;
}
```